# Getting sum of my object array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have object array:

```
[Income] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Today] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Sum] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Total] => 61.9700
                                    )
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [Sum] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Total] => 60.2300
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Today] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Sum] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Total] => 51.9500
                                    )
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [Sum] => Array
                                    (
                                        [Total] => 53.6900
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

How to correctly sum `Total` for each level?

```
Income->[0]->Today should be 122.20
Income->[1]->Today should be 105.64
```

i have tried this:
EDIT:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($item->Today);$i++){
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($item->Today as $amount) {
        if(is_object($amount[$i]->Sum->Total)){ 
        echo $amount[$i]->Sum->Total;
        $total += $amount[$i]->Sum->Total;
        }
    }
    if($i==0){
        echo '<td>'.$total.'</td>';     
    }   
}
```

i got  this error Warning: main(): Cannot add element Today number 3 when only 0 such elements exist in. .. updated my post with code i use now

i have it as object from XML not array
i know something is wrong!I m still struggling to learn multidimensional arrays :(

Comment: Income seems to be a key in your array. So you can't acces to it using `Income` but using `$myArray['Income']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$income;
for($i = 0; $i < count($income["Income"]); $i++) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($income["Income"][$i]["Today"] as $amount) {
        $total += $amount["sum"]["Total"];
    }
    $income["Income"][$i]["Today"] = $total;
}
```

Just put your data array `$income=//your data`

Comment: i have it as object from XML not array

Comment: i told object array

Comment: I did modify your code and got ther result i m after but i get 122 instead of  122.20and i got  this error Warning: main(): Cannot add element Today number 3 when only 0 such elements exist in. .. updated my post with code i use now

Answer (score 1):

You need foreach :

```
$array=array();
foreach($arr['Income'] as $key=>$val){
    $array['Income'][$key]['Today']=0;
    foreach($val['Today'] as $k=>$v){
        foreach($v as $keys=>$values){
            $array['Income'][$key]['Today']=$array['Income'][$key]['Today']+$values['Total'];
        }
    }
}

print_r($array);//your output.
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/915160da0177f756a9fbac7d95ad5a572fa055b9)

Comment: i have it as object from XML not array

Comment: @IngusGraholskis your posted data  doesn't look like object it is array.Share the proper data.above code is for displayed data in question.

Comment: its $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

Comment: and then i do: foreach($XML->xpath('path/to/Income') as $item) {